# Aligning output on the right in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << right << "Hello" << setw(10) << "World\n";
    cout << right << "Goodbye"  << setw(10) << "World\n";
}
```

Why does this result in output like:

```
Hello    World
Goodbye    World
```

Rather than:

```
Hello    World
Goodbye  World
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout    << "Hello"  <<  " World";
    cout << right << setw(10) << "today\n";
    cout   << "Goodbye"  <<  " World";
    cout << right << setw(10) << "today\n";
}
```

If I try this, why is the "today" part misaligned?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the order of the operators to solve this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(10) << "Hello" << "World\n";
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(10) << "Goodbye" << "World\n";
    return 0;
}
```

- You have to place all operators **before** the value you like to format.
- Avoid using `using namespace std`.

The `std::setw()` operator sets the field with for the next value. And the `std::left` or `std::right` operators set the position of the value in this field.

This example

```
std::cout << std::left << std::setw(10) << "word1"
    << std::right << std::setw(20) << "word2" << std::endl;
```

Will create this kind of formatting:

```
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
word1                    word2
```

You see there is a first "field" with 10 characters in which the first text is placed, and a second "field" with 20 characters in which the second word is placed right aligned. But if the text in the first field is longer than the field, this happens:

```
AAAAAAAAAA....BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
word1istoolong               word2
```

The second field is just shifted the number of characters. The stream never keeps track of the *current position*, it just build the output using "fields" of a given size.

To justify text for a given page with, use code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>

const int pageWidth = 78;
typedef std::list<std::string> WordList;

WordList splitTextIntoWords( const std::string &text )
{
    WordList words;
    std::istringstream in(text);
    std::string word;
    while (in) {
        in >> word;
        words.push_back(word);
    }
    return words;
}

void justifyLine( std::string line )
{
    size_t pos = line.find_first_of(' ');
    if (pos != std::string::npos) {
        while (line.size() < pageWidth) {
            pos = line.find_first_not_of(' ', pos);
            line.insert(pos, " ");
            pos = line.find_first_of(' ', pos+1);
            if (pos == std::string::npos) {
                pos = line.find_first_of(' ');
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}

void justifyText( const std::string &text )
{
    WordList words = splitTextIntoWords(text);

    std::string line;
    for (WordList::const_iterator it = words.begin(); it != words.end(); ++it) {
        if (line.size() + it->size() + 1 > pageWidth) { // next word doesn't fit into the line.
            justifyLine(line);
            line.clear();
            line = *it;
        } else {
            if (!line.empty()) {
                line.append(" ");
            }
            line.append(*it);
        }
    }
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    justifyText("This small code sample will format a paragraph which "
        "is passed to the justify text function to fill the "
        "selected page with and insert breaks where necessary. "
        "It is working like the justify formatting in text "
        "processors.");
    return 0;
}
```

This example justifies each line to fill the given page with at the begin. It works by splitting the text into words, filling lines with these words, and justifies each line to exactly match the width.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich Sorry, I copied the wrong example. Now it's fixed and works as expected.

Comment: @Flovdis Why should one avoid using `using namespace std` ?

Comment: What if the cout was like cout << "hello" << " world " << " today\n"; and you wanted to right justify today?

Comment: @user3340001 In this case just put the operators *before* the "today" string. All operators are applied to all following values in the stream.

Comment: @user3340001 Or probably I misunderstand your question. Can you explain what you mean with "right justified"?

Comment: If I try this : cout   << "Hello" << " World"  << left << setw(10) << " today\n"; it doesn't work

Comment: I want "today" to be pushed all the way to the right, and the "hello world" to stay on the left.

Comment: @user3340001 You can't do this with the `std` operators. If you want to "justify" text like in text processors, you have to do this programatically. Maybe you update your question to make this clear.

Comment: Why can't you? I just want the "today" part to be pushed to the right side by like 10 width lengths using setw, I've seen it done before but I can't find the source.

Comment: @user3340001 If you have always two words, you can do something like this: `std::cout << std::left << std::setw(10) << "Word1" << std::right << "Word2" << std::endl;`

Comment: @Flovdis look at my example given, I edited my question above. I just want the today part to be indented and aligned.

Comment: @user3340001 I added more explanation how the stream formatting works. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, at the point you call `setw`, the output stream does not remember about printing `"Hello"` or `"Goodbye"`.

Try this to produce the output you desire:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << left << setw(10) << "Hello" << "World\n";
    cout << left << setw(10) << "Goodbye" << "World\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution using std::format (C++20):

```
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("{:10}{:}\n", "Hello",   "World");
    std::cout << std::format("{:10}{:}\n", "Goodbye", "World");
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately only MSVC >=19.29 currently supports `std::format` by default, [according to cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20). [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/eoGxzzxd4) is a running example. Oh, and of course in thge meantime `fmt::print` [is also possible](https://godbolt.org/z/qMxroMW56)... Anyhow, +1 for providing a modern solution as alternative :-)

Comment: cppreference is not always up to date. All major standard libraries support std::format: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724059/does-gcc-support-c20-stdformat

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```cpp
    cout << right << "Hello" << "\t" << "World\n";
    cout << right << "Goodbye"  <<  "\t" << "World\n";
```